# TYPO3 extension - reuse existing frontend

Tags: html, css, typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

I created a new custom extension *'customext'* in TYPO3. My goal is to reuse the frontend part of the well-known **news** extension.

In the *customext* I have a simple db which stores *title* and *description* of toy elements. I would like to reuse the graphical property of the news extension.

I'm struggling to understand/find/adapt the .css/html files of the news extension relevant to my needs.

Comment: If you want to override the template of the news extension, you could follow this documentation. https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.0/en-us/Tutorials/Templates/Start/Index.html#changing-paths-of-the-template 

You just need to override the template path and adjust the frontend according to your template

Comment: please add version information: TYPO3, ext:news

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ: Typo3 11.5.19, ext:news 9.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays most sites are based on Bootstrap.
Especially `ext:news` comes with a bootstrap HTML-markup by default.

If you want to reuse the news-templates you can set the paths(1) for your templates (that of your extension) to the same stack of paths(1) of the news extension.

Otherwise copy the templates and modify.
regarding the CSS: either stay with the (bootstrap) standard or identify the complete (and maybe adapted) CSS. Identify all relevant CSS rules with a browser inspector. So you can identify all necessary HTML markup: Which tags need to be present? which classes and ids?

---

Consider that your site / site-extension might have overrides for the news-templates.

(1) FLUID has three sets of paths:

- Layouts
- Partials
- Templates

each can have multiple entries building a priority list for existing files, which is to be used for rendering.